# adding addFieldsToFilter() does INNER JOIN on eav tables, removing all products which don't have that attribute

Tags: product-attribute, eav, scope

This is either a simple fix, or something that magento does natively and I'll have to do a workaround (which I still need to know what it is).

Here is my code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=>'type_id','eq'=>'simple'),
        )
    )
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=>'student_grades', 'eq'=> ''),
            array('attribute'=>'student_grades', 'eq'=> '68,69'),
        )
    )
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->load(1);
```

And it generates this SQL (I have <<bracketed>> the join that is the problem):

```
SELECT `e`.*,
IF(_table_student_grades.value_id>0, _table_student_grades.value, _table_student_grades_default.value) AS `student_grades`,
`cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
-- problem is here!!
<<INNER JOIN>> `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `_table_student_grades_default` ON
    (_table_student_grades_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND
    (_table_student_grades_default.attribute_id='177') AND
    _table_student_grades_default.store_id=0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `_table_student_grades` ON
    (_table_student_grades.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND
    (_table_student_grades.attribute_id='177') AND
    (_table_student_grades.store_id='264830')
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
    cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND
    cat_index.store_id='264830' AND cat_index.category_id='312798' AND
    cat_index.is_parent=1 
WHERE ((e.type_id = 'simple')) AND
    (
    (IF(_table_student_grades.value_id>0, _table_student_grades.value, _table_student_grades_default.value) = '') 
    OR 
    (IF(_table_student_grades.value_id>0, _table_student_grades.value, _table_student_grades_default.value) = '68,69')
    )
```

**THE PROBLEM**
what is happening is the `INNER JOIN` is excluding products that don't have this attribute at all - and I don't want to add this attribute globally and unnecessarily fill the tables - that's what EAV is supposed to be all about.

How do I force a left join for this attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EAV models like the product, `addFieldToFilter` is just there for compatibility with the collection interface, it calls `addAttributeToFilter` which has an additional third parameter `$joinType` that defaults to "inner".

```
public function addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')
```

So instead of `addFieldToFilter($conditions)`, you can use `addAttributeToFilter($conditions, null, 'left')` to force a left join.