# How to pass a complete SQL query to the model?

Tags: product-attribute, sql, magento-1.4

This is v1.4.x to be clear.

I have recently found a limitation in the Magento-generated query for products, cited in this thread:

[adding addFieldsToFilter() does INNER JOIN on eav tables, removing all products which don't have that attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105485/adding-addfieldstofilter-does-inner-join-on-eav-tables-removing-all-products)

On that subject, I started searching for a way to pass a complete SQL query to the model, but have not found any way listed.  Is this possible?  Again, this is a limited case and Magento unfortunately does an INNER JOIN with no remedy when I need a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this for future readers, ignoring the fact that you don't need it anymore because there is a simple solution to your original problem.

You can modify the `Zend_Db_Select` instance for any collection, which means that you can effectively change the query to anything.

Here is a simple and stupid example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)->where('foo=bar');
```

But be aware that many collections make their own changes in the `_beforeSave()` method or using an observer.

Comment: Although this is not passing the entire query, the where clause is what I wanted to modify (all other Magento methods seem to be accommodating), and a solution has been posted to my other question referenced above.  Thanks for not being a "forum snob" and answering the specific question I gave. :)

Comment: Actually "where" was just an example, if you have a look at Zend_Db_Select you will see that you can modify other parts as well